# How does one write a VBS or batch file that will automatically install a Google Chrome plugin?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, batch-file, google-chrome-extension, vbscript

I need to find a way to install a Google Chrome plugin onto Chrome automatically. It would be preferable if you gave advice pertaining to .bat and .vbs files as that is where my "specialties" lie.

When I say automatically, I mean you would double-click the script and it would put the plugin onto the browser.

C:\Documents and Settings*UserName*\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions

Is where the extension data is. I'm working with Windows machines, by the way.

EDIT: Sorry, the vibe I was intending to give off was "advice" not "gimme free code".

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I intended to say. Please point me in the correct direction is what I really intended to say.

Comment: I have not attempted to create code because I do not know where to start. I will do what I can, but need advice on how to make VBS happy with .json or just a whole new alternative.

Comment: As I stated sample code would be *helpful*.

Answer (score 1):

Where to start..

There are some limitations you will have to deal with, due to [security measures](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/protecting-windows-users-from-malicious.html) taken.

1. Your extension must be published in the Chrome Web Store.
2. Your extension will start disabled in Chrome [with a prompt to enable it](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/12/no-more-silent-extension-installs.html).

If you can live with that, the procedure is outlined [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions#registry). Don't ask me for sample code, but it should be pretty straightforward.

In short, all you need is to create a registry key based on the extension ID. Chrome will pick that key and add an extension - but will ask the user to confirm.

Comment: Ok. The plugin is already published (that part was work in its own right), and I can live with the second part. Thank you again.